# How do you declare an event on a WinRT Custom Control

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a custom control in a WinRT app I am experimenting with.

I declared it like this, and it works as expected:

```
public event RoutedEventHandler AdvertMoreInfoButton_Clicked;
```

CodeAnalysis complains that I need to declare it correctly, I have googled about for ages this morning, but cannot find any solution that will Code analysis is happy with.

What codeAnalysis says:

CA1009  Declare event handlers correctly
    Declare the second parameter of 'MyApplication.MyCustomEventHandler' as an EventArgs, or an instance of a type that extends EventArgs, named 'e'.

Comment: Your code fragment and the error message don't seem related.

Comment: I renamed things when I copied from visual studio.  If I rename AdvertMoreInfoButton_Clicked to MyCustomEventHandler would that help?